SharePoint Designer Workflow Issue
We are using SharePoint 2019 on-prem. I created a workflow in SharePoint Designer for an employee feedback list.  The workflow is set so that if the admin approval status equals approved, then an email is sent to the employee's manager to let them know they have to review/approve the feedback.  I tested the workflow when it was published, and it worked as expected.  However, I've heard from a few people that they are receiving multiple emails to review the feedback.
Why is the workflow sending multiple emails?  Do I need to add another step to end the workflow after the email has been sent?
The workflow is started when an item is changed, since there is a person that accesses the list to changed the admin approval status.
